# Getting this error when trying hyperparamter tuning in python

Tags: python-3.x, hyperparameters

I am receiving this error when attempting hyper parameter tuning and do not know how to fix can anyone assist?

I imported from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV

```
then ran 

n_estimators_array = [1, 4, 5, 8, 10, 20, 50, 75, 100, 250, 500]
results = []
for n in n_estimators_array:
forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=n, random_state=76)
forest.fit(x_train, y_train)
result = accuracy_score(y_test, forest.predict(x_test))
results.append(result) 
print(n, ':', result)
```

and got this result:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [105], in <cell line: 1>()
  1 for n in n_estimators_array:
----> 2     forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=n, random_state=76)
  3     forest.fit(x_train, y_train)
  4     result = accuracy_score(y_test, forest.predict(x_test))


NameError: name 'RandomForestClassifier' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

So far it seems that you have not imported RandomForestClassifier.

Try this line of code:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
```

For more information visit:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html